# Attach workbook to send by VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, attachment

I have VBA code attached to an Excel button. When pressing the button the Outlook mailbox will appear, ready to send the mail.

The workbook is not attached to the mail. I think something is wrong with `.Attachments.Add`.

```vb
Dim xRg As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error Resume Next
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

Set xRg = Intersect(Range("D7"), Target)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 200 Then
    Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
End If

End Sub


Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()

Dim xOutApp As Object
Dim xOutMail As Object
Dim xMailBody As String
Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
xMailBody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 2"
On Error Resume Next
With xOutMail
    .To = "Email Address"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "send by cell value test"
    .Body = xMailBody
    .Attachments.Add "W\Desktop\Files\Workbook1
    .Display   'or use .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set xOutMail = Nothing
Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: its "w:\Desktop\Files\Workbook1 and not "w\.....

Comment: `"W\Desktop\Files\Workbook1` there's no closing `"`.  The file name should have the extension - `Workbook1.xlsx`.  The drive designation should be followed by a colon: `W:\\``.     An error is being thrown, but `On Error Resume Next` is hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code is not complete:

```
.Attachments.Add "W\Desktop\Files\Workbook1
```

The `Add` method of the `Attachments` class creates a new attachment in the `Attachments` collection. The source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name), for example:

```
.Attachments.Add  "C:\Test.xslx", olByValue, 1, "Test"
```

I'd also suggest specifying a local file path.